# Worker thread in START_NOT_STICKY service

Tags: android, service

I am confused about `START_NOT_STICKY` in android. And here is two questions:

1. I don't need call `stopself` explicitly for `START_NOT_STICKY` service as it would stop itself after onStartCommand, right?
2. If a start a workerThread in the service, would it continue to run after I return START_NOT_STICKY? Why I wonder that is the service should be stop it self after return START_NOT_STICKY
3. If my service implements both onStartCommand and onBound, where should I call stopSelf?

EDIT (from android doc)

For started services, there are two additional major modes of operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they return from onStartCommand(): START_STICKY is used for services that are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while `START_NOT_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT are used for services that should only remain running while processing any commands sent to them.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a service will not stop itself after it returns from `onStartCommand()`. Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics).

START_* values only indicate to the system what it should do if, for some reason, the system decides to kill the Service. 
You still should call `stopSelf()` or `stopService()` to stop the running Service otherwise the service will run indefinitely or until the system decides to kill its process.

When android system kills a process in which a Service was running, it tries to re-create it when possible based on the value returned from onStartCommand().

- If the value returned was `START_STICKY`, it will recreate the Service process and will call onStartCommand() with any pending Intents or null (if no pending Intents).
- If `START_NOT_STICKY` was returned, the system will create the Service process again and will call onStartCommand() only if there are any pending Intents.

Hence, START_NOT_STICKY will guarantee that your Service will not start only if system decides to kill your Service and also if there are no pending intents.
Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) to understand `START_NOT_STICKY`

Comment: From [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle) link - `In cases like this, stopService() or stopSelf() does not actually stop the service until all clients unbind.`. So, you should call `stopSelf` once all components have unbind from the Service.

Answer (score 0):

Vijay,
You should ask your question in a separate thread but here is the solution

You can achieve this by implementing a BroadcastReceiver. 
Create a receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml: -

```
<receiver android:name="com.demo.bootup.BootupBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Make sure that you have proper permissions set

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

Now in your `onReceive()` method you can start your Service.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Intent bootupIntent = new Intent(context, BootupService.class);
   context.startService(bootupIntent);
}
```

Make sure that you call your Service class instead of BootupService.class